# Como hacer un juego del ahorcado

Tags: java, array

tengo que hacer un ahorcado y no estaría pudiendo hacerlo.

No se como poner los guiones, y que si acierta la palabra se quite el guion, no se como relacionar la matriz con el array.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String [] palabras= {"sangre", "comida", "cocina", "asalto", "aceite", "chicle"};
        String [][] matriz= {{"s", "a", "n", "g", "r", "e"},{"c", "o", "m", "i", "d", "a"},{"c", "o", "c", "i", "n", "a"},{"a", "s", "a", "l", "t", "o"},{"a", "c", "e", "i", "t", "e"},{"c", "h", "i", "c", "l", "e"}};
        String res,letrau;
        String [] oculto = null;
        int [] n=new int [6];
        
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                n[i]=(int)(Math.random()*6);
                System.out.println(palabras[i]); //palabra a adivinar
            }
              for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    oculto[i]="_";
                }
                
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
                letrau=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese letra");
```

Comment: [¿Bajo qué circunstancias puedo agregar "urgente" o frases similares a mi pregunta para obtener respuestas más rápido?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4771) Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask].

Comment: tu codigo esta incompleto y no compila te recomiendo poner un [mcve]

Comment: Seguramente haya una posibilidad mejor pero siempre está la opción de borrar la consola y volver a escribir todo remplazando un guión por la letra. Te recomiendo que tengas una matriz con las letras que el usuario ya ha escrito y que elimines la matriz que se llama matriz. Te respondería con codigo pero no me ha quedado muy claro lo de como es jugar a ahorcado con 6 palabras a la vez.